# what's the best strategy of validating multiple user input?

Tags: c#, wpf

currently I have an app that has a window where has multiple TextBoxes, CheckBox, etc., receiving user data input. but the user data requires to be validated. since what kind of data user is required to input is not certain, therefore i may have to add extra controls programmatically.

following is my brief demo:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Don't care" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="78"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="93,16,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="414"/>
        <Label Content="Important1*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="78"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="93,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="414"/>
        <Label Content="Importtant2*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="78"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="93,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="414"/>
        <Label Content="Reserved for Programmatically added." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="188" Width="497"/>
        <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

please notice that `Don't care` need not be validated in such case.

to valid each, i have implemented `ValidationRule` so that it will be done automatically. however, i need to know if all data is validated when user push the submit button, so that i can ensure user did a good job.(or maybe the button is disabled if not all user data is validated)

so my question is, is there any clean way for me to validate all the fields that is important for me(in such context, with `*` followed)? notice that, the programmatically added controls may be bound to important fields too.

---

UPDATE:

why i don't do everything in xaml? (binding, validation)

because every time, the window will work on different object, and what fields this object will have are uncertain. so i have to bind and validate data accordingly. therefore, i have `Reserved for Programmatically added.` in my demo.

the way i validate is

```
BindingOperations.GetBinding(textbox, TextBox.TextProperty).ValidationRules.Add(new PositiveIntegerValidate());
```

where:

```
public class PositiveIntegerValidate : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int i;
        if (!int.TryParse((string)value, out i))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Not Integer.");
        if (i <= 0)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Less than or equal to 0.");
        else
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

validates integer fields.

i have other validation rules but it's irrelevant.

Comment: You could always create a `OnTextChanged` event and attach to all of the textboxes. Then inside you can use `Regex` to ensure the data is the correct format, and enable the Submit button.

Comment: @Ckrempp sure that works. but i feel like that's kind of redundant, since i have exactly the same code in `ValidationRule` subclasses. so i am trying to find a smarter way.

Comment: Why not use a Grid for allignement rather than all margins?  Why not bind in XAML?  Post your validation.  You can validate multiple properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Blam maybe you can make your opinion clearer by stating more. about your why's, i think you could find all answers in my post.

Comment: great. why down vote? this is a serious problem.

Comment: A serious problem without a lick of sample code.  That XAML you have posted does not give a clue as to how you are validating.  The link I posted is a sample of how to validate multiple fields.

Comment: Validation in wpf is per control. It's to validate binding. Then binding will set value, done. To validate window, you have to allow validation per control still works, but with a *copy of data*. When user press `Ok` button, this copy will pass another validation pass (to example, ranges min/max can be compared at this time) and will be assigned to a real data. `Cancel` button will simply dispose copy of data without doing anything.

Comment: @Blam please see my update. to be honest, i don't think posting that will help with raising a solution. what i am trying to find is a way to validate a class of data.

Comment: @Sinatr what's you suggestion of implementing the validation pass? is there anyway to reuse the result of validation rules?

Comment: So the question is about validation and posting your validation code will not help with a solution but posting some XAML that has no binding nor validation will help?  As stated that link does validate a class of data.

Comment: @Blam so what's your suggestion? my xaml shows what my app looks like. sure it's better than pure plaintext description. i am trying to go straightforward to my problem. as my title said, i am asking a strategy of validation. the detail of validating should not matter.

Comment: What does that XAML have to do with the problem?  It has not bind and does not even have a name for you to access the control.

Comment: @Blam so you suggest i should delete it or not. the way you blame me never solves a problem.

Comment: Blame?  Does that XAML have anything to do with the problem?  No.  Have to posted code to reproduce the problem?  No.

Comment: @Blam no need for further discussion. i think you are the only one who can't understand my problem after looking at the ui. and the way you go keeps others away from my post.

Comment: So where are the answers that understand the problem?  Really two arbitrary outboxes and button clarifies the problem.  Based on margins and no binding those posted controls are not created by code behind.  You have tried nothing and are making stuff up as you go.  That is why you have no answers other than the correct answer from me that you can cannot understand because you have tried nothing.

Comment: @Blam good guess. god blesses you.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?
Validation only has 5 properties and one of them is HasError

[Validation.HasError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.haserror(v=vs.110).aspx)